# Can I have, from a manually entered id, fill in the automatic cells in a Powerapps form?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-selected-items

I have mounted a form in PowerApss which is linked to different databases.

One of those databases contains more than 500 IDs, so what I want to do is apply a kind of "VLOOKUP" but in such a way that it fills in the name of the person, his email, and his position in the form so that save time filling it out.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The default field can than be:

Default := First( Filter( NameDB, ID = Gallery.Selected.ID )).Name
Where your gallery is the once containing the ID and the NameDB the database which holds your database information about names.

You use First( Your record ).Name to only get the name value of ONE record.
With this construction you can retrieve Names, Email addresses et cetera.